# Making sense out of plotting 3D graphs in octave/matplotlib

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, octave

Recently I have a few times I wanted to plot 3D graphs in some applications (tried matplotlib and octave), noticing similar syntax, but I don't understand what it does so its hard to modify it according to my needs. Here an **[octave example](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plotting.html)**:

```
 tx = ty = linspace (-8, 8, 41)';
 [xx, yy] = meshgrid (tx, ty);
 r = sqrt (xx .^ 2 + yy .^ 2) + eps;
 tz = sin (r) ./ r;
 mesh (tx, ty, tz);
```

What does `meshgrid, r, tz` do/refer to? Suppose I want to plot something like

```
f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2+2xy^2 +1
```

How might I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`meshgrid`, as its name suggests, returns a grid of points at which you can evaluate your function. In your example `xx` and `yy` are 41x41 matrices. I can't print them here so let me use a simpler example: `[xx, yy] = meshgrid (-1:1, 10:10:30)`. This returns

```
xx =

-1     0     1
-1     0     1
-1     0     1


yy =

10    10    10
20    20    20
30    30    30
```

Can you see how `xx` and `yy` allow you to generate every point in the grid? (Mentally pick a row/column pair; take the $x$ value from `xx` and the $y$ value from `yy`.)

To calculate function, $f(x,y)=x^2 - y^2+2xy^2 +1$, we need to bear in mind that `xx` and `yy` are matrices, so we need to use dots for element-wise multiplication, as follows:

`f = xx.^2 - yy.^2 + 2*xx.*yy.^2 + 1`

Finally, we plot the function using `surf(xx,yy,f)`:

[image: Surface plot of the function f(x,y)=x^2 - y^2+2xy^2 +1]

(Note that I used the original `linspace (-8, 8, 41)` grid rather than the one in my previous example to generate this plot.) `surf` is like `mesh` except that it uses shading. You will immediately understand the difference if you try it for yourself.

What's going on in the Octave code is that the author was worried about division by zero (since the function to be plotted, `tz` is $\sin(r)/r$), so (s)he added a small number (`eps`) to `r` to ensure positivity. You do not have such a problem so our definition was more straightforward.